# What kind of script is it? (photo attached)

Tags: kanji, history, calligraphy

The marker is on the top of a hill on the way to Yawata Hachimangu in Kyoto Pref. The site seems rather not significant historically, there were no other related signs around.

The top character is Sanskrit (probably), four kanji look like 國分寺跡 (although I am not sure of 分 as the strokes do not follow the regular order).

The real question is: what kind of script is the second character from the top written in? Is it somehow compressed 山号?

[image: Historic Marker in Yawata]

Comment: 「鳩峰」かな.......??

Comment: are you suggesting the top two characters are the same script?

Comment: 一応、サンスクリット語じゃなくて漢字です。。「鳩峰國分寺跡」 だと思います、たぶん・・・

Comment: Well... There is a connection between 鳩峰 and 岩清水八幡宮 http://www.tesshow.jp/saitama/tokorozawa/shrine_kme_hato.html

Comment: @Shoko and this blogger also thought the same http://godzillagogo.web.fc2.com/070521.html I'm impressed :)

Comment: ^ わ、よく見つけましたね。。 I googled too but found nothing... ^^;  btw, your photo is way better than the blogger's :p

Comment: 「鳩**ヶ**峰」（はと**が**みね）と書いてあるような気がします

Comment: @naruto あっ、ほんとだ！「ヶ」みたいなのがありますね。「ケ」を入れて「鳩ケ峰国分寺跡」でググると、ようやく[若干ヒットしました](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%E9%B3%A9%E3%82%B1%E5%B3%B0%E5%9B%BD%E5%88%86%E5%AF%BA%E8%B7%A1%22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kanji written in a different style. I don't know enough to identify exactly which style, but it looks like a type of 草書体 (you can compare different styles [here](http://lightbox.on.coocan.jp/html/fontImage.php?session=&s=38&x=8&w=530&y=55&height=570&font=kouzansousho&backColor=402720&textColor=D6D9D0&u8=1&TitleText=%E9%B3%A9%E5%B3%B0%E5%9C%8B%E5%88%86%E5%AF%BA%E8%B7%A1&a=0&bd=0&backColorImage=FFFFFF&url1x=0&url1y=0&url1t=100&url1=&check=1))

The characters are: 鳩ヶ峰國分寺跡